# Quoted Identifier - EF Code First

Tags: c#, sql-server, oracle, entity-framework, oracle11g

Is there any option in EF 6 to create table in Oracle with nonquoted identifier?

**Background:**

We have been using EF Code first. Till now product was supposed to support SQL Server, now Oracle is added by PO. For most of the functionalities, we have used EF models with LINQ to populate data but for few special functionalities, we have written engine which generates sql queries.

**Example:**
*Select Col1, Col2, Col3 From Tab1*

So above generated query works fine with SQL Server database because EF generated tables with nonquoted identifier in SQL Server.

But the same query doesn't work in Oracle as EF generated all tables with quoted identifier. So to execute above query successfully, engine will have to generate:

*Select "Col1", "Col2", "Col3" From "Tab1"*

I want to avoid changes in query engine.

So, is there any option in EF 6 to create table in Oracle with nonquoted identifier?

Many thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick here is that you don't need to suppress quoted identifiers, you just need to force all your identifiers to all caps.  In Oracle identifiers that aren't quoted are converted to all caps in the catalog.  Then when parsing SQL, Oracle converts non-quoted identifiers in the SQL to all caps to match the identifiers in the catalog.

This is how Oracle creates the illusion of a non-case-sensitive catalog.

You can force your entities and properties to map to all-caps database identifiers using Attributes, the Fluent API, or a custom convention.

Here's an idea of how to use Custom Conventions to normalize the Oracle table and column identifiers to be all-caps-with-underscores (assuming they Entity Properties and CLR type names are PascalCase).

```
namespace OracleConventions
{
    using System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Pluralization;
    using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

    static class Identifiers
    {
        public static string CreateIdentifier(string entityName)
        {
            var result = Regex.Replace(entityName, "[a-z][A-Z]", m => m.Value[0] + "_" + m.Value[1]);

            return result.ToUpper();
        }
    }

    public class AllCapsTableAndColumnConvention : System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions.Convention
    {

        public AllCapsTableAndColumnConvention()
        {
            var ps = (IPluralizationService)DbConfiguration.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(IPluralizationService), null);

            this.Types().Configure(t => t.ToTable(Identifiers.CreateIdentifier(ps.Pluralize(t.ClrType.Name))));
            this.Properties().Configure(p => p.HasColumnName(Identifiers.CreateIdentifier(p.ClrPropertyInfo.Name)));           

        }
    }
    public class AllCapsForeignKeyConvention : IStoreModelConvention<AssociationType>
    {

        public void Apply(AssociationType association, DbModel model)
        {
            // Identify ForeignKey properties (including IAs)  
            if (association.IsForeignKey)
            {
                // rename FK columns  
                var constraint = association.Constraint;
                foreach (var p in constraint.FromProperties.Union(constraint.ToProperties))
                {
                    p.Name = Identifiers.CreateIdentifier(p.Name);
                }

            }
        }

    }

}
```

You would then register the conventions in OnModelCreating

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new OracleConventions.AllCapsTableAndColumnConvention());
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new OracleConventions.AllCapsForeignKeyConvention());
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```